# Is VimGolf Compatible with Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I followed the VimGolf install instructions using **Ruby 2.0.0**, and got a `command not found` out of it. I switched over to 1.9.3 (via RVM) and did the same, and it works like a charm.

Is VimGolf not compatible with Ruby 2.0 yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You propably forgot to do:

`gem install vimgolf`

after you switched to Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Oh, no! That's what I meant when I said I installed VimGolf with Ruby 2.0. I RVM'd to Ruby 2.0 (which is actually my default) and did a gem install. After the install, I ran vimgolf setup and got a command not found.

Comment: OK what does `$ which vimgolf` gives you?

Comment: Nothing, from the looks of it.

Comment: Seems like your RVM doesn't symlink properly the gems executables or you haven't added the folder to your PATH. Can you do a `$ gem install bundler` and right after it's installed succesfully a `$ bundle -v` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: OK, if you do a `$ gem list` you should see `vimgolf` in that list (supposing it was installed succesfully). If that is the case, do a `$ which bundle` and you should get something like `/Users/George/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/`. Then do a `ls /Users/George/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/` and inside there you should see the vimgolf executable. Do you see it? Do you see any other executables in that folder?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28387/discussion-between-agis-and-jordan-thornquest)

Comment: Hey, I finally got this working. It was a setup issue with RVM and my path. Since your answer and comments were especially helpful, I'll give it to you ;)